# Ramifications of using delayed durability on an ASP.NET session database?

Tags: sql-server, session-state

Is anyone aware of a reason why I shouldn't apply delayed durability (forced) to a production ASP.NET Session database?

I've read through the documentation and it seems to meet all the criteria for use as far as data loss not being paramount, the db also runs in simple recovery.  I was seeing a heavy dose of writelog wait_types from sys.dm_exec_requests, which seemed to propagate to sessions not getting updated/users getting kicked out of our system.  I saw no reason to limit the scope of delayed durability to particular transactions, so forced seemed the way to go.  I've applied the setting and traffic appears to be flowing fine, but wanted to check with the stack group if anyone ran into anything specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little over a week later it appears as though throughput's been good with our ASP.NET Session State database.  No queued up collection of logwaits in dm_exec_requests during session updates/cleanup.  Forms Authentication errors seem to be usual client disconnects, so the aggregate dropped significantly in comparison to when contention issues were faced.